# finding gradient to specific x-value

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I have a set of data in a numpy array - x-values, lets say between 0-100, and y-values. I need to get the gradient to a specific x-value ex. x=20 but I can only get the np.gradient function to give me the gradient at a certain index-value. right now I have:

```
g=np.gradient(y)
print(g[20])
```

but this of course gives me the gradient at i=20 and not x=20

I have both the x and y values in one 2D array and 2 x 1D arrays defined in my script

EDIT:
I actually came to solve it like this:

```
def grad(x, value):
    def find_nearest(x, value):
        x = np.asarray(Timeppmh)
        idx = (np.abs(x - value)).argmin()
        i = x.tolist().index(x[idx])
    return i
    g=np.gradient(yp,x)
    find_nearest(x,value)
return g[find_nearest(x,value)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value 20 is in `x` you could just do `j[x == 20]`. However, if that is not the case, you would need to approximate the gradient value. You can use for example linear interpolation.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 80)
print(20 in x)  # 20 is not in x
# False
y = x * x + 3 * x + 2
# Pass x as second argument for value spacing
g = np.gradient(y, x)
print(np.interp(20, x, g))  # Should be 43
# 43.00000000000001
```